# What is the difference between a Matrix4 "World Transform" and "Local Transform"?

Tags: c#, opengl, matrix

For [*my GameEntity class*](http://pastebin.com/5EmSwL2K), I have a single Matrix4 which represents an Entities Location, Rotation, and Scale, while also having individual fields for those variables which update the Matrix4 "EntityMatrix" whenever they are changed or edited. I felt as though this was an optimal design decision, but then I found [*this class on the internet*](https://github.com/skooter500/XNA-Physics-with-Bepu/blob/master/Steering/Steering/GameEntity.cs), which shows another implementation.

I noticed on line 40 and 41 that they have added two Matrix4s, instead of just one like I did. The names of the Matrices also confuse me. WorldTransform and LocalTransform. Does anyone know what these two Matrices are used for? How do they represent different things; what is the difference between the them?

Comment: I would start here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/ or read your class book and class notes. I'm assuming "Local Transform" is transforming the "Model" coordinates in my link, and "World Transform" transforms "World" coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `worldTransform` field is similar to the matrix in your `GameEntity` class. There are some key discrepancies, though, in that it only takes in to account the position, and not the rotation or scale. But just like in your class, it is supposed to change when the position of the entity changes.

The `localTransform` field is separate, and it does NOT change in response to the properties of the entity. It's `public`, though, which means it can be set elsewhere. It probably gets set once, when an entity is created, and then never changes. You would likely use it to compensate for some translation/rotation/scale offsets in a model file, e.g. if the model file uses one axis as "forward" but the game engine uses a different axis. The `localTransform` field is initialized to identity, so if it never gets changed it won't interfere with other matrix calculations.

Comment: Any idea why they opted for two Matrices then, instead of just one?

Comment: @Krythic I have an idea. The `worldTransform` changes automatically with the properties (in theory, anyway), and the `localTransform` doesn't. `localTransform` in this case is like a special, custom transformation component, in addition to position, rotation and scale. If you just used one matrix, whenever the position/rotation/scale changed, the matrix would be re-computed, and you'd lose any additional transformation you had tried to apply.

Comment: @Krythic That is, the two matrices have different meanings/uses and are updated differently, but they still both contribute to the final position of an entity.